# Track amount owed, but request static payment amount

Tags: quickbooks

I am working with a new client and our agreement will total $50,000 over the 10 month project. We have agreed on billing in ten $5,000 payments.

However, we (both parties) would like to track expenses/services as they are incurred, regardless of the amount due. So one month, the amount generated could be $6,000, the next month it could be $3,000, but both months the payment due would be $5,000. (see below)

Month          Amount Incurred          Payment Due          Balance
1                          8,000                          5,000                  3,000
2                          3,000                          5,000                  1,000
3                          2,000                          5,000                 -2,000
4                          6,000                          5,000                  1,000
5                          9,000                          5,000                  3,000
6                          4,000                                        5,000                  2,000
7                          4,000                          5,000                  1,000
8                          6,000                          5,000                  2,000
9                          2,000                          5,000                 -1,000
10                        6,000                          5,000                          0

How would I go about creating invoices that show the actual amount incurred each month, but only reflect a payment due of the agreed-upon $5,000 (even if that means that they are paying more than actually has been incurred to date)?

Comment: If you just want an invoice.  [As long as you know what the previous payment was you can use Intuit's invoice template generator.](https://quickbooks.intuit.com/r/free-invoice-template/).  If you want to be able to generate an invoice automatically, that might not be possible, your request is very specific and not easily automated.

Comment: Automation is not necessary. 

I tried out the template generator and couldn't figure out how to set a specific amount due that does not align with the balance of the items entered.